# where does the data I passed using putExtra() method of intent to another activity get stored?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

my Question is :

1 - If I send data to another activity where does it stored ?

2- what is the difference between put the parameter key of putExtra() method as builtin predefined string like EXTRA_TEXT and  put a key with a random name 
like "mymessage"
i.e 
what is the difference between this code

```
 public void go(View view)
{
    String mytxt="hellow";
    Intent i=new Intent(this , SecondActivity.class);
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT , mytxt);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

and this code

```
 public void go(View view)
{
    String mytxt="hellow";
    Intent i=new Intent(this , SecondActivity);
    i.putExtra("mydata" , mytxt);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

3- how does android use the key part to of putExtra method to refer to my data

4- how does getExtra() method work from where it get the data

I think that 3 ans 4 are relevant by nature to the other above parts but I want to be clear about all my questions

thanks in advance

Comment: I think this is a pretty good question. It's the sort of thing you stop asking, but now I want to know too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1 - If I send data to another activity where does it stored ?

I think there are a few different ways to answer this question, but the most straightforward is: it doesn't matter.

When you use an `Intent` to send data to another activity, what *matters* is that the other activity will receive an `Intent` object that is populated with the data you sent. The exact mechanism of *how* that happened is something you (as a developer) aren't supposed to care about.

The only exception to this that's worth mentioning is the fact that data in an `Intent` **might** (depending on exactly what you're doing) be subject to "Binder transaction size limits"; your data is serialized and transmitted at some point and, if the data is too large, this will fail.

> 2- what is the difference between put the parameter key of putExtra() method as builtin predefined string like EXTRA_TEXT and put a key with a random name like "mymessage"

There is no technical difference. In fact, `Intent.EXTRA_TEXT` is defined as a simple string itself (`"android.intent.extra.TEXT"`).

The practical difference is that `Intent.EXTRA_TEXT` is a well-defined, *known* value that any developer can use. If I'm writing a chat program, and I want to let other apps open mine and hand off message text, I can tell users that I'll look for `Intent.EXTRA_TEXT` for this data, and it will be easy for everyone to use.

Within your own app, it really doesn't matter what strings you use for the key in a `putExtra()` call. As long as you use the same string later on to look it up, you can use anything you want. The only concern here is to make sure that you don't accidentally use the same key for two different values within the same `Intent`.

> 3- how does android use the key part to of putExtra method to refer to my data

It doesn't. All the android framework does is take a bunch of key-value pairs, serialize them (if necessary), and transmit them to another activity. That other activity, however, can then use the keys to look up the values. That's why e.g. `Intent.EXTRA_TEXT` is cool; it's a well-defined key that anyone can use to look data up, counting on callers on the other side to have put something in the map using that known key.

> 4- how does getExtra() method work from where it get the data

I guess you could say that the data comes from the app's memory.

You can think of the `Intent` object as being a really fancy `Map<String, ?>`. The same way you could write `String s = (String) map.get("key")`, you can write `String s = intent.getStringExtra("key")`.

Comment: could you please explain this line "android.intent.extra.TEXT" .                                 
and what if I want to send data with size bigger than 1mb how to avoid the failure ?

Comment: Any `String` can be used as a key for extras. The android platform just happens to have provided everyone with some existing strings to use (like `Intent.EXTRA_TEXT`). It doesn't really matter _what_ string `EXTRA_TEXT` happens to hold, but it turns out that it holds `"android.intent.extra.TEXT"`. As for how to avoid the error if your data is more than 1mb in size, you just have to not use intents for that. Within your own app, perhaps you could do something like write the (large) data to disk or to a db, and then use the Intent to send a lookup key so the other activity can read from disk/db.

Answer (score 1):

Your answers are as follow.

**1.** When we move from one Activity to another Activity, then data is passed using Intent and this data is sent to the system OS for safe keeping for restoration later, when we reach to another activity this data is restored from OS, There is a limit of 1 MB of this data, If It crosses then we get a crash 
"TransactionTooLargeException" for nougat+ android devices.

**2.** Intent.EXTRA_TEXT is basically a predefined string in Intent class.

```
    public static final String EXTRA_TEXT = "android.intent.extra.TEXT";
```

Google has coded internally for this key, suppose If we want to share a text with an application then we send this predefined key to send that "text" which need to be shared, thus It is a **Standard** Reserved key for which Google has coded internally to get and utilize that text

```
 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 i.setType("text/plain");  
 i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "my sharign text here");
```

and on the other side, If we send any our key suppose "my_key" then we handle this on the other activity.

**3/4.**
When you pass on data from Activity 1 using putExtra() method, then all the data sent through putExtra() is packaged into a bundle, We can fetch this whole bundle in Activity2 using getExtras() method, or we can get our separate key value using getStringExtra(), getIntExtra(), getBooleanExtra() etc.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you send extras to an activity, the extra data is not stored in a physical device like internal/external storage, but it is stored temporarily in RAM.
2. `Intent.EXTRA_TEXT` is a constant defined in the class Intent:

   `public static final String EXTRA_TEXT = "android.intent.extra.TEXT";`

it is used with intents like sending emails and not passing data to activities, although it is not prohibited.

3. (and 4) The key part of the extra data is used to refer to the actual value of the data: 
    
   `intent.putExtra("key1", "A");`  
   `intent.putExtra("key2", "B");`

    when the activity that opens wants to retrieve the extra values sent to it by the parent activity, it will check the keys:

`if(getIntent().hasExtra("key1")) 
    String value1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("key1", "");`